# How to get length of the fields which has duplicate values in firebase (Like Categories)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the below code, itemCount is taken place based on total documents.
But I need to do it on the total Category it has.

ie... there are only 5 categories in my firestore data and there are around 20 documents.
So when I use listView.Builder, it iterates for 20 times...

```
                       ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return filters(
                              snapshot.data[index]['subCategory']);
                        });
```

How can I do it in a better and efficient way...

Comment: Add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: @PeterHaddad https://ibb.co/mBkWXqM

Comment: Orderby won't work, you can't check if a query contains the only way is to retrieve the 20 documents and then use exists to check if a field is inside the document and add the 5 documents in a 5 list

Comment: Thank you,  you can post that answer with code...i will check it...

Comment: You will still retrieve  20 documents though

Comment: what to do ???....any idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218067/discussion-between-asbah-riyas-and-peter-haddad).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this workaround...Is there any better option...???

```
  Set subCat = {};

  Future getItems() async {
    final QuerySnapshot itemList = await _fireStore
        .collection('Product')
        .where("category", isEqualTo: widget.category)
        .getDocuments();
    itemList.documents.forEach((element) {
      subCat.add(element.data['subCategory']);
    });
    return itemList.documents;
  }
```

Thus the length of the subCat will give exact length without duplicates..